# How to add dynamics to a static HTML page?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, wysiwyg

What's a quick'n easy way to add edit function to static HTML? I could save HTML with a textproperty and an /admin area to edit the entity with the variable that contains the HTML but is this a good solution or can you recommend a better solution?

I'm considering using the tool appengine_admin and 2 model: `Content` and `AdminContent` so that a change the static HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0059)http://www.teknator.se/eddaconsult/management_services.html -->
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0" name="GENERATOR"></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<center>
<p>
<table border="0" width="600">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><font color="#666666" size="+2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Management Services</b></font>
      <p><font size="-1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Management-for-hire</b>...
```

To an editable page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0059)http://www.teknator.se/eddaconsult/management_services.html -->
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0" name="GENERATOR"></head>
{{body}}
```

Is this a solution you would support or could you make me some contructive criticism that I might be doing this wrong since I might not be doing it right if a save HTML in a textproperty?

I was thinking 2 simple models like these

```
class AdminContent(appengine_admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Content
    listFields = (
        'body'
            )
    editFields = (
        'body'
        )

class Content(Model):
    body = db.TextProperty(verbose_name='text')
```

Then every page can have an ID and dynamic content and I can finish this case real quick but is the solution too "dirty" since the variable will mix markup and actual content and I should try to make a real HTML editor instead?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a CMS. Rather than reinventing the wheel, you should probably use [an existing one](http://code.google.com/p/vosao/).

Answer (score -1):

First identify the bits of the static HTML you want to edit - make them variables. Then use php to generate dynamic content

Comment: The OP is using Python on App Engine. Telling him to use PHP is not helpful.